# escaping double quotes in external command

Tags: bash

I want to use double quotes ("") into an external command in bash script. For example:

I want

```
result=$(hg log "one to three")
```

traduced literally in

```
hg log "one to three"
```

not to

```
hg log 'one to three'.
```

Any idea?

Comment: There's no difference between `hg log "one to three"` and `hg log 'one to three'`, and the command substitution you listed executes precisely that command. Do you want to pass an argument to `hg log` that contains double quotes, as in `hg log '"one to three"'`?

Comment: Is for dates interval in `hg log "$date1 to $date2"`. That not work with `hg log '$date1 to $date2'` because `hg log '2015-01-23 to 2015-12-01'` doesn't work

Comment: That's not a shell expansion problem, you just forgot to give `hg log` the `-d` flag along with the date specification. Try `result=$(hg log -d "$date1 to $date2")`.

Comment: I don't forget that, this is my command `filelist=$(hg log -k $dev -d "$start to $end" --template "{file_mods}{file_adds}\n"`. Doesn't work in bash script. Activating -x in bash, I can see that `-d '$start to $end'`

Comment: There replace `"$start" to $end"` with `"$start to $end"`, you have a double quote in the middle that doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Wintermute sorry, I write command wrong here, but still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69593/discussion-between-jgd-and-wintermute).

Answer (score 0):

Storage the result in one array is the solution. For example:

```
revisions=($(hg log -d "$start to $end" --template "{ rev}\n"))
```